# .js files not included in page when using Django Form Assets (Media class) with crispy forms

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm reproducing the basic example in the Django documentation ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/)) about how to include .js or .css files automatically with custom calender widget:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
class Media:

    js = ('test.js',)
```

When using that CalenderWidget in a field defintion of a simple form, the test.js file is not injected in the page. I'm using Crispy forms to render the form in my template so I assume that this should be the source of the problem...

For now, I have to add myself the {{ form.media }} tag in my template to force the test.js file to be added to the page but I would like to find a way to make things more "automatic" like it supposed to be...

Thanks a lot

Comment: I didn't find this question until I went to the github issues list for this project.  You might try renaming your title a little -- Maybe include the words form.media, media, static

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now...and have found a workaround or two.

Start with:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
```

Then:

1) You can add the form.media to your output, but that assumes your form is called form in your context..

```
        self.helper.layout.append(Layout(HTML("{{ form.media }}")))
```

2) You can call self.media.render() - which I think is better:

```
        self.helper.layout.append(Layout(HTML(self.media.render())))
```

You could probably also call insert() instead of append.